# get the position of Text in UITextview

Tags: ios, position, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a UITextView with CGRect (0,y,320,58) and centered align Text, I want the position of the text in the UITextView

```
 _________________________
|                         |
|     Hey how are you?    |
|_________________________|
```

I want the position/padding of the text from the left how will I get it

Comment: Hay @user1201239 how to get position of text.

Answer (score 2):

UITextView adopts the UITextInput protocol. That protocol has the method -`firstRectForRange:` which will tell you the rectangle covering a range of characters.

Comment: Or, for the sake of future readers, if the text in question wraps, use [`sectionRectsForRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614458-selectionrectsforrange?language=objc) to get all of the individual `CGRect` values...

Comment: as of 2020 in Swift 5, this method has been renamed [selectionRects(for range: UITextRange)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614458-selectionrects)

Answer (score 1):

If the Text is inside a UILabel which is inside the UIImageView then u can get the y position of the label by

```
CGFloat yPosition = [self.myLabel.frame.origin.y];
```

if not then do use a Label and set it to ur desired position in the UIView in storyboard.
get the Text y position with respect to the Imageview.

hope this helps.

Comment: i think his problem is with a UITextView

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this property of the the textView

**textContainerInset**

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM, RIGHT);
```

Comment: This is to set the position of the containerInset whereas I want to retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be help full...

```
UITextView *textStuff = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textStuff.frame = CGRectMake(2.0, 200.0, 200.0, 40.0);
textStuff.text = @"how are you today?";
textStuff.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UITextPosition *Pos2 = [textStuff positionFromPosition: textStuff.endOfDocument offset: nil];
UITextPosition *Pos1 = [textStuff positionFromPosition: textStuff.endOfDocument offset: -textStuff.text.length];

UITextRange *range = [textStuff textRangeFromPosition:Pos1 toPosition:Pos2];

CGRect result1 = [textStuff firstRectForRange:(UITextRange *)range ];

NSLog(@"%f, %f", result1.origin.x, result1.origin.y);

UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:result1];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2f green:0.5f blue:0.2f alpha:0.4f];
[textStuff addSubview:view1];

[self.view addSubview:textStuff];
```

Print to "CGRect result1" and see It's returning posting of text...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did it this way ,

```
UITextPosition *post = [_textview beginningOfDocument];


CGRect r = [_textview caretRectForPosition:post];
```